# Facebook Graph API V2.10

Tags: facebook, user-interface, facebook-graph-api

According to the facebook documentation after, 90 days I wont be able to reply comments using the API.  Is my understanding correct?

Checkout the facebook documentation comment:

> 90-day Deprecations in Graph API v2.10
>
> POST and DELETE operations for the /{comment-id} node and the /{object-id}/comments edge will now be restricted to Pages with valid page access tokens.

Answer (score 0):

It means, 90 days from July 18th, 2017 - from the day that v2.10 was introduced. After the 90 days, you cannot use the feature anymore.

Comment: But with this I wont be able to reply comments using the API,  correct?